# EventData message lost with log4j2 as SLF4J backend?

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2, event-log

I want to use SLF4J-ext EventData and EventLogger to log important events in my business-logic:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    EventData messageEvent = new EventData();
    messageEvent.setMessage("Message arrived");
    messageEvent.put("messageID", message.getJMSMessageID());
    EventLogger.logEvent(messageEvent);
}
```

I also want to use log4j2 as a backend. Currently, this leads to the following artifacts being part of my deployment: slf4j-api-1.7.12, slf4j-ext-1.7.12, log4j-api-2.3, log4j-core-2.3, log4j-slf4j-impl-2.3, log4j-web-2.3 - as well as their dependencies, of course.

My log4j2-configuration is intended to produce a formatted entry in regular files:

```
[...]
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="traceFileAppender"
        fileName="${logBase}/trace.log"
        filePattern="${logBase}/trace.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%date{ISO8601}[%thread] %level %marker %logger%nThread-Stack: %x%nThread-Map: %X%nMessage-Map: %K%nMessage: %m%n%rEx-- %n%n" />
        <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
    </RollingFile>
    [...]
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    [...]
    <Logger name="EventLogger" level="INFO" additivity="true" />
    [...]
    <Root level="TRACE">
        <AppenderRef ref="traceFileAppender" />
        [...]
    </Root>
</Loggers>
[...]
```

However, my log-statements look like this:

```
2015-07-31T08:13:55,589[MessageListenerThreadPool : 0] INFO EVENT EventLogger
Thread-Stack: []
Thread-Map: {}
Message-Map: {messageID=ID:c3e2d840d4d8d4f14040404040404040cf522d11eb57d22b}
Message: 
--
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log4j-slf4j-impl module [converts](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/xref/org/apache/logging/slf4j/EventDataConverter.html) an slf4j EventData object to a log4j2 StructuredMessage. The output shows the message ID, proving that this conversion was successful.

However, the output does not show the message. Looks like this is due to the [StructuredMessage.toString()](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/StructuredDataMessage.html) implementation. At first glance it looks like it may not be possible to customize this by specifying a key for the message part with the `%K{key}` conversion specifier... :-(

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I investigated some more and noticed that there are XML-Exceptions in my logs, complaining about a non-stax2-compliant implementation. The applications are supposed to be running on WebSphere, and according to [this blog-entry](http://veithen.github.io/2013/10/02/broken-by-design-websphere-stax.html), there is not much I can do about it.

Comment: I think it should be possible to write a custom converter that attempts to get the EventData object from the structured message and then appends the output manually to reflect the original expected output.